# able to focus but not type in input box using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, textinput

Basically i have a series 5 rows of text boxes (each row contains 3 columns) and single text area ...tabbing at the end of column3 should take it to to the text area and then tabbing from the text area should take me to the  next row of input/text boxes .

the code below works to the extent of tabing through the  row1 , taking me from row1 col3 to textarea_desc  and then tabbing on textarea_desc shifts the focus to row2 col1 however i cannot see the cursor appear on row2 col1...if I added css it hsows up in row2 col1 but the no cursor so i cannot type in text i have to click on row2 col1 for the cursor to appear can some one tell me why ?

```
 $('input[type="text"],textarea').on('focusout',  function() {
        var box_class=$(this).attr("class");
        var row_id=$(this).parents('ul').attr('id');    


        if (box_class.indexOf("col3")>=0) {
            $("#textarea_desc").focus();
            $("#prev_row").val(row_id);
        }
        if (box_class.indexOf("textarea_desc")>=0) {
            var prev_row=$("#prev_row").val();

            var new_row=$("#prev_row").val().match(/\d+/);
            new_row="#row"+(parseInt(new_row)+1)+"-col1";


            $(new_row).focus();


        }

    });
```

html ....

```
 <ul id="row1" class="row">
                    <li class="col1" >1.</li>
                    <li class="col2"><input type="text" size="26" class="row1-col1" id="row1-col1" /></li>
                    <li class="col3"><textarea cols="28" rows="1"  class="row1-col2  textareainp" id="row1-col2" ></textarea></li>
                    <li class="col4"><input type="text" size="10" class="row1-col3 " id="row1-col3" /></li>
                </ul><ul id="row2" class="row">
                    <li class="col1" >2.</li>
                    <li class="col2"><input type="text" size="26" class="row2-col1" id="row2-col1" /></li>
                    <li class="col3"><textarea cols="28" rows="1"  class="row2-col2  textareainp" id="row2-col2" ></textarea></li>
                    <li class="col4"><input type="text" size="10" class="row2-col3 " id="row2-col3" /></li>
                </ul>
<textarea cols="40" rows="7"  class="textarea_desc" id="textarea_desc" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="prev_row" class="prev_row" value="" />
```

Comment: Are you setting `tabindex` for the elements?

Comment: nope. but i am able to tab from row1 col1 to row1 col3 to the text area just not back from the text area to the row col1 ( i can add value to row2.col1  $(new_row).focus().val('hello'); and it shows up in the text box ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `focusout` is happening because of the `TAB` and the `TAB` event will put the focus automatically on next element. You will need to catch the `TAB` key and then use something like this:

```
$("*:focus")
```

This will give you the current focused element. Use this in your function.

Also, you need to call this:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Working code:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 9: // TAB
            event.preventDefault(); // Stop from changing focus

            $this = $("*:focus");

            var box_class=$this.attr("class");
            var row_id=$this.parents('ul').attr('id');    

            if (box_class.indexOf("col3")>=0) {
                $("#textarea_desc").focus();
                $("#prev_row").val(row_id);
            }
            if (box_class.indexOf("textarea_desc")>=0) {
                var prev_row=$("#prev_row").val();

                var new_row=$("#prev_row").val().match(/\d+/);
                new_row="#row"+(parseInt(new_row)+1)+"-col1";


                $(new_row).focus();
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: cheked... but now i am not able to move from col1 to col2 or col3 (tabbing) but col3 to text area and text area to row 2 works...

Comment: So, are you still having issues?

Comment: okay i added movement of col1 to col2 and col2 to col3 ...will accept your anser

Comment: no not really... jsut some missing stuff if (box_class.indexOf("col2")>=0) {
                var new_row1="#"+row_id+"-col3";
                $(new_row1).focus();
                
            }
             if (box_class.indexOf("col3")>=0) {
                var new_row2="#"+row_id+"-col4";
                $(new_row2).focus();
                
            }

Comment: just one question :....if i am dynamically generating the text boxes the $("*:focus") doesn't seem to work ... any work around for that...

Comment: Then you will have to save the current focused element in a jquery variable for using later. You can do that whenever you are calling `focus()`.

Comment: hey just wnated to reach out and ask you question ... the code thaty ou have  given works fine . I have expanded on it considerably... however i have hit an issue and this really quirky... if chnage row1col1 input box  a function is called to check if the old value matches the new  if not a ajx call is made (checkval fucntion...) after the ajax call the focus should move to row1col2 a  textarea...the funny thing is it does briefly focus on  row1col2 textarea and jumps to row1col3 (an input box)....i ma not able to figure this out. it works in ie and chrome.. http://jsfiddle.net/2tBvP/

Comment: but not in firefox.. mind you if i dont make the ajax call it works perfectly its the ajax call that makes it jump across the textarea

Comment: Are you calling the code to change focus from inside `success` handler of AJAX?

Comment: no from outside.. but i did try to chnage the focus within the success line 99 , line 100 in the jsfidde

Comment: basically look at line 175,176,179